# Python duplicate list values from index to another

Tags: python, numpy

Let's say I have this numpy array :

```
first_array = [[1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
               [1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
               [0. 1. 0. 0. 0.]
               [0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]
               [0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]
               [0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]
               [0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]]
```

and I have this 2 lists :

```
index_start = [50, 80, 110, 120, 150, 180, 200]
index_end= [70, 90, 115, 140, 170, 190, 220]
```

I want to create a new 2D numpy **output_array** where I iterate by column **first_array** and duplicate each value of every row from an **index_start** to an **index_end**.

*1st iteration -* For example **first_array[[1,1]] = 1, index_start[1] = 50** and **index_end[1]=70** then the first column of my output_array will have the value 1 from index **50** to **70**.

*2nd iteration -* Then **first_array[[2,1]] = 1, index_start[2] = 80** and **index_end[2]=90** then the *first* column of my output_array will have also the value 1 but from index **80** to **90**.

*3rd iteration -* **first_array[[2,3]] = 1, index_start[3] = 110** and **index_end[3]=115** then the *second* column of my output_array will have the value 1 from index **110** to **115** and so on.

Here's what I have tried but this is giving me wrong result :

```
first_array = [[1, 0, 0, 0, 0,],
               [1, 0, 0, 0, 0,],
               [0, 1, 0, 0, 0,],
               [0, 0, 1, 0, 0,],
               [0, 0, 1, 0, 0,],
               [0, 0, 1, 0, 0,],
               [0, 0, 0, 0, 1,]]
index_start = [50, 80, 110, 120, 150, 180, 200]
index_end= [70, 90, 115, 140, 170, 190, 220]
last_index = max(index_start+index_end)
output_array = np.zeros((last_index, 5))

for i in range(len(index_start)):
    for j in range(last_index):
        for k in range(5):
            output_array[index_start[i]:index_end[i]]=first_array[i][k]
```

Answer (score 2):

It's working now. I forgot to add the k column index at the output_array. Here's the final working code if anyone needed this.

```
first_array = [[1, 0, 0, 0, 0,],
               [1, 0, 0, 0, 0,],
               [0, 1, 0, 0, 0,],
               [0, 0, 1, 0, 0,],
               [0, 0, 1, 0, 0,],
               [0, 0, 1, 0, 0,],
               [0, 0, 0, 0, 1,]]
index_start = [50, 80, 110, 120, 150, 180, 200]
index_end= [70, 90, 115, 140, 170, 190, 220]
last_index = max(index_start+index_end)
output_array = np.zeros((last_index+1, 5))

for i in range(len(index_start)):
    for k in range(5):
        output_array[index_start[i]:index_end[i]+1, k]=first_array[i][k]
```